# Create seperate columns from factor variables column in R

Tags: r

I'm pretty sure this is very straight forward but I'm bangning my head against the wall right now trying to figure it out.

I have a dataframe which looks something like this

```
a <- data.frame(years=c(2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013), names=c("John", "Daniel", "John", "Daniel", "John", "Daniel", "John", "Daniel"), income = c(20, 15, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 55))

  years  names income
1  2012   John     20
2  2012 Daniel     15
3  2013   John     60
4  2013 Daniel     50
5  2012   John     40
6  2012 Daniel     30
7  2013   John     20
8  2013 Daniel     55
```

I want to restructure the data so that it's aggregated (sums the income value where the years and names values are the same, and creates seperate columns for the 'years' columns, basically something like:

```
   names  2012  2013
1   John    60    80
2 Daniel    45   105
```

I've been messing with group_by and summarize, but can only seem to find ways of generating a single rather than multiple columns.

Appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it just in one line with `pivot_wider` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
a %>% pivot_wider(names_from = years, values_from = income, values_fn = sum)

#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   names  `2012` `2013`
#>   <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 John       60     80
#> 2 Daniel     45    105
```

`pivot_wider` not only lets you to reshape your data, but also allows you to apply a function to the reshaped data.

---

To help you understand, it is like doing this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

a %>% 
  group_by(years, names) %>% 
  summarise(income = sum(income), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = years, values_from = income)
```

Answer (score 2):

In `base R`, using `tapply`:

```
tapply(a$income, list(a$names, a$years), sum)
       2012 2013
Daniel   45  105
John     60   80
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

a %>%
  group_by(years, names) %>%
  summarise(income = sum(income)) %>%
  arrange(desc(names)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = years, values_from = income)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  names  `2012` `2013`
  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 John       60     80
2 Daniel     45    105
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
b <- aggregate(a$income, by=list(a$names, a$years), sum)
tidyr::pivot_wider(b, values_from=x, names_from=Group.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `xtabs` from `base R`

```
xtabs(income ~ names + years, a)
#       years
#names    2012 2013
#  Daniel   45  105
# John     60   80
```